# ng-bootstrap datepicker CSS issue

Tags: ionic3, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

The datepicker model box is too small. How to make it a normal size as ng-bootstrap? I just copy/pasted the code and haven't made any custom CSS changes.

[image]

[image: It should look like second image]

Comment: thats not shrunk, thats the default size

Comment: mast3rd3mon Its not the regular size as in ng-bootstrap. There must be some way to fix it. pls help if you have any idea.. trying to fix it from past 5hrs

Comment: yes, it is. i even went onto their [website](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) and checked. please do the same

Comment: Well I did not find any solution in that website. So posted question. I know it seems very silly question but this is taking lot of time to crack it.

Comment: what are you wanting it to look like? because it looks like it should currently (according to their website)

Comment: I face the same issue , did you got a any solution?

Comment: Yeah, just increase the base font size i.e html, body{font-size:*increase-here}

Answer (score 0):

There is a default size for the datepicker modal. Since your `input box` has a bigger size, the `datepicker modal` looks small.

Give width to your `input-group` and then do this:

```
input.form-control ~ ngb-datepicker {
  width: 300px; //same width as input group
}
```

This will make the datepicker modal to expand its width. However you will still have to apply css to inner elements of the modal to expand them as well.

Comment: In this case only the calendar width changes and inner elements will not be auto adjusted. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I found the answer. Its happening because my font family base size is less. Fixing the base size solved the problem